# Changing app widget background color programmatically

Tags: android, widget, background-color

How do I set the background color of the home screen app widget programmatically?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Remember widget is remoteView. You have very limited resource to updates UI of widget and not directly.

You can try :

```
remoteViews.setInt(viewId, "setBackgroundColor", Color.BLACK);
```

I never used it but i guess it may be the way.

I guess you need to change color dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

You can change color of ImageView image in "RemoteViews" by doing this:

```
remoteviews.setInt(viewid, "setColorFilter", color);
```

Comment: android.widget.Button doesn't have method: setColorFilter(int)

Answer (score -2):

```
Widget.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
```

Answer (score -5):

Find the following code..

code:

```
  Button button;

    //to change background color..

    button.setBackgroundColor(Color.Yellow);
```

Comment: And where exactly does the Button reference come from? This is in an AppWidgetProvider.

Answer (score -6):

use

```
 Yourwidget.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

hope help

Comment: Your solution not working with App widgets, couse you can not have direct access for change properties of widget (only by using broadcast messages)