# Changing background of a button in widget: Android

Tags: android

I need to change `background` of a button programmatically. That button is placed in a widget.

I got an example of changing background color [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10876610/changing-app-widget-background-color-programatically), but this is only for changing color, and I want to use an image instead of a color.

Is there any way to apply a background image to a button programmatically?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using `setBackgroundColor` like in the example you linked you should be able to use `setBackgroundResource` I think.

Comment: @SanjayJoshi fine take your time :)

Answer (score 3):

In Your AppWidgetProvider class:

```
private RemoteViews v;
... in onUpdate:
v = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
...
icon = context.getResources().getIdentifier("ic_action_refresh_"+choosenTheme, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
v.setInt(R.id.wi_bu_refresh, "setBackgroundResource", icon);
```

Where:

icon is just resource id (found by getIdentifier method dynamically for every theme).

R.layout.widget is widget xml layout.

R.id.wi_bu_refresh is a button in widget layout, which background You want to change.

Hope it helps, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
setInt(YouButtonId, "setBackgroundResource", YourImageResourceID);
```

Answer (score 0):

use `setBackgroundResource` instead of `setBackgroundColor` .

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to use `public void setBackgroundResource (int resid)`