# Android: Change shape color programmatically for widget

Tags: java, android, android-layout, widget, android-widget

I'm trying to change color of the shape for my widget programmatically.

My widget layout looks like this:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@drawable/transparent_color"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/btn03_off" />
</FrameLayout>
```

In my settngs activity, I'm changing background shape and image programmatically. And I need to change the color of the shape too.

```
 views.setInt(R.id.button, "setBackgroundResource", R.drawable.rounded_conners);
 views.setImageViewResource(R.id.button, mImageResId);
```

I can't figure out how to set color to the shape for my widget. I can do it in activity like this:

```
 ((GradientDrawable) mPreviewImageView.getBackground()).setColor(colorId);
```

But this is not working with widget, because I have no reference to my button.

Thank you

Comment: See this link: http://blog.syedgakbar.com/2012/07/changing-color-of-the-drawable-or-imageview-at-runtime-in-android/

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. Unfortunately setColorFilter is changing only foreground image color (src image) but I need to change background shape color :( So close!

Comment: I can set color filter, but unfortunately only for foreground image (in src) and I have to chage it in background :( any suggestion?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you well. Do you want to change the widget background? if so, then refer to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10876610/changing-app-widget-background-color-programatically

Comment: I need to have my shape drawable as background views.setInt(R.id.button, "setBackgroundResource", R.drawable.rounded_conners); and foreground image views.setImageViewResource(R.id.button, mImageResId); so I cant use setBackgroundColor because it override my background shape...

Comment: @Sandak did you find a solution for this?